# Automating Chrome Cast Ambient Mode settings or Google Photo Album content

Tags: google-cast, google-photos, google-cast-sdk, google-photos-api

I want to rotate out/toggle two images within my Chrome Cast's Ambient Mode (via Google Photo Album).

Possible routes that I see:

1. Delete image 1 and add image 2 of an album one day, the next delete image 2 and add image 1.
2. Each day, switch the selected Album within the Ambient Mode settings.

Methods I see:

1. https://developers.google.com/cast/, however there doesn't seem to be any mention of settings or ambient mode. I suspect these methods are not public.
2. ifttt, sadly I don't see anything even remotely along these lines already out there.

Is this possible, where could I look?

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43463046/edit) the question to be on-topic: include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

The Ambient mode content is managed by the Cast platform based on the selected content you have provided. There isn't an API to be able to control what content is selected to be displayed.